# Retrieving UserPicker Widget emnail string using onValueChanged

Tags: google-app-maker

I am new to app maker. When working with the User Picker widget which allows for a drop down selection of valid email address within a domain, logging the newValue under onValueChanged would output [object Object] instead of the email address selected. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That is because in the property editor, you are selecting the option `valueIsRecord`. According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#UserPicker):

> **valueIsRecord** *boolean*   Whether the value property is a primitive value or record.

If this checkbox is selected, the **newValue** is set to the the user object record hence you are getting [object Object]; However, if the checkbox is not selected the value will be primitive, therefore it will give you an email address.

[image]